# Request to API works in Postman but not when I try with laravel/guzzle

Tags: laravel, api, postman, guzzle, dingo-api

I make an API and now I try to access to that API.
WIth Postman everything is perfect and works fine:

[image]

but when I try the same with guzzle/laravel with code:

```
$res3 = $client3->post('https://app.EXAMPLE.com/api/update/'.$serial, [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$res2['token'],
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ],

    'form_params' => [

      'token' => $res2['token'],
        'bookingdate' => '07/07/2018 12:00 am',
        'notes' => $SpecialRequests
        ]
]);
```

I got:

Object

> data : debug : class :
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException"
>   file : "/home/user_name/public_html/vendor/dingo/api/src/Auth/Auth.php"
>   line : 113

What is a problem? WHy works in Postman but won't work with Laravel/Guzzle library?

Answer (score 5):

In Postman, it looks like you are sending the token as a request parameter. In your code, it looks like you are using form_params, which are application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Try this:
http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#query-string-parameters

`$res3 = $client3->post('https://app.EXAMPLE.com/api/update/'.$serial, [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$res2['token'],
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ],
    'query' => [
      'token' => $res2['token'],
      'bookingdate' => '07/07/2018 12:00 am',
      'notes' => $SpecialRequests
    ]
]);`